# spark streaming visualization

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, visualization

I am using spark streaming to stream data from kafka broker. I am performing transformations on the data using spark streaming. Can someone suggest a visualization tool which I can use to show real-time graphs and charts which update as data streams in?

Answer (score 1):

You could store your results in [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) and then use [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) to perform visualizations.

Comment: Recommendations of a tool or library should include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and ideally [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from looking at spark's own streaming UI tab, I highly recommend use of [graphite sinks](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics). Spark streaming is a long running application so for monitoring purposes this can be really handy.

In no time using graphite dashboards you will kick start monitoring your spark streaming application.

The best literature I know is, [here](http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2016/09/30/spark-streaming-on-yarn/) in section monitoring. and [here too] (https://www.inovex.de/blog/247-spark-streaming-on-yarn-in-production/)

It provides configuration and other details. Some of the dashboards you will find ready-made in json format on some or other github links but again I found these two posts most useful in my production application.

I hope this will help you for visualizing and monitoring your application internals in spark streaming application.

Answer (score 0):

you have use Websockets for building real-time streaming Graphs. 
As such there are no BI tools but there are JS libraries which can help in building real-time graphs - http://www.pubnub.com/blog/tag/d3-js/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Lightning: A Data Visualization Server

http://lightning-viz.org/

The server is designed to for making web-based interactive visualizations using D3.  It is designed for large data sets and continuously updating data streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pro BI Tools like Tableau, Power BI or even MS Excel.. For testing, I use MS Excel with 1 min auto refresh.

You can also write python code for this.